# How to move contacts from an old iTunes backup into my iPhone?

Tags: itunes, iphone

I just upgraded my iPhone from IOS 2.5 to IOS 5.01, and it's erased all of my contacts.

I'm panicking, as it will take months to get the contacts back - and in some cases, I'm never going to be able to get them back.

I do have a backup of my phone which was taken 1 month ago, sitting on another laptop - is there any way to extract the contacts from this backup, and load them back onto my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

iTunes always takes a backup of your data before upgrading your phone and it `usually` replaces all the contents back to your phone **unless** you upgraded using a jailbreak version. Assuming you upgraded legally and something magically happened that didn't let the restore to happen, you can get your contents back from:

Mac: ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/

Windows: \Users(username)\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\

Check out [apple support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The backup/sync process via iTunes backs up the contacts. The creat being there is no way to manage them or restore only contacts back to the device at a later time.

Sync your iPhone with iTunes to update your iPhone's backup. Use the utility provided or a similar type utility to extract and save this data from your iPhone's backup on your computer. After this data is extracted and archived on your computer, you can erase all from your iPhone.